# MySQL Selecting between ANY and ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql Table T1 consisting of two columns of INTs that links a car_id to a part_id. A single car_id can have multiple part_ids, and the same part_id can correspond to more than one car_id. For example,

```
car_id   part_id
  1        1  
  1        2  
  1        8  
  2        3  
  3        4  
  4        2  
  4        6  
     ...  
  10       1  
  10       2  
     ...  
  20       1  
  20       2  
  20       8
```

To get all the part_ids associated with car_id = 1, I run the query,

```
SELECT car_id, part_id FROM T1 WHERE car_id=1
```

and get the result:

```
car_id   part_id
  1        1  
  1        2  
  1        8
```

Now, I want to find all the remaining car_ids that contain at least (say >= 2/3) of the part_ids associated with car_id=1. (In this example, I should get all car_ids that have at least 2 of the part_ids 1,2, and 8 as shown after my SELECT query. So, I should get car_ids 1,10, and 20).

I can find the car_ids that contain All of the part_ids 1,2, and 8 using:

```
SELECT car_id, part_id 
      FROM T1 
      WHERE part_id = ALL (SELECT part_id FROM T1 WHERE car_id=1). The result is car_ids 1 and 20.
```

I can find the car_ids that contain ANY of the values 1,2, and 8 using:

```
SELECT car_id, part_id 
       FROM T1 
       WHERE part_id = ANY (SELECT part_id FROM T1 WHERE car_id=1). The result is car_ids 1,4,10 and 20.
```

How can I specify some number between ANY and ALL?

Comment: tell what u expect for result. write a wished result

Answer (score 1):

To get all `car_id`s that have 2 or more of car `1`'s `part_id`s do

```
SELECT car_id, 
       group_concat(part_id) as part_ids
FROM T1
WHERE part_id in (SELECT part_id FROM T1 WHERE car_id = 1)
group by car_id
having count(distinct part_id) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select car_id
from (select cp.car_id,
             sum(case when cp.part_id is not null and cp1.part_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as PartsInCommon,
             sum(case when cp.part_id is not null and cp1.part_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as ThisCarOnly,
             sum(case when cp.part_id is null and cp1.part_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as ThatCarOnly
      from CarParts cp full outer join
           (select part_id
            from CarParts cp
            where car_id = 1
           ) cp1
           on cp.part_id = cp1.part_id
      group by cp.car_id
     ) t
where PartsInCommon / (PartsInCommon + ThisCarOnly + ThatCarOnly) >= 2.0/3
```

This query counts the number of parts common to both cars or in one or the other. The `where` clause then defines the particular condition.

If you want the list of parts, then Juergen has the right idea with the `group_concat()`, although you don't specify this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. I have tried as much as i can

```
SELECT 
    car_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(part_id)
FROM cars
WHERE FIND_IN_SET
    (part_id ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(part_id) FROM cars WHERE car_id = 1)) 
GROUP BY car_id
HAVING COUNT(part_id) >= 2
```

Here is the sqlfiddle Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e563/17